# How to use multiple properties inside typeORM function for checking duplicate on update

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nest, nestjs-typeorm

I'm working on NestJS and using TypeORM to connect with MS SQLSERVER. Now I'm working on **update** function. I want to check if the updated data is duplicated or not except itself.

So, I want to make something like,

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblproducts WHERE product_no = :updatedProductNo AND product_no != :currentProductNo

It will return **0** if it is the same data or the updatedProductNo is a new one, otherwise, it will return **1** if the data is existing.

So I made the my code be like this,

```
const productExist:number = this.productRepository.countBy({productNo: updateProductDto.productNo, productNo: Not(currentProduct.productNo)});
```

But I will get the error

> An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.

Please help.

Comment: You can use your primary key as second condition to exclude itself in the count, `const productExist:number = this.productRepository.countBy({productNo: updateProductDto.productNo, id: Not(currentProduct.id)});`

Comment: If productNo is unique, you can set unique index in your entity definition.  Refer: https://typeorm.io/indices#unique-indices

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the QueryBuilder to write multiple conditions on the same field

```
const queryBuilder = productRepository.createQueryBuilder('product');

const productExist = await queryBuilder
.where('product.productNo = :productNo', { productNo: 
updateProductDto.productNo })
.andWhere('product.productNo != :currentProductNo', { currentProductNo: 
currentProduct.productNo })
.getCount();
```